# How can I change the "licensed to" in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

How can I change the "licensed to" in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition? I have not found a solution for Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

Comment: Is this a question or answer? The SE network is a question and answer network. The question and answer should be separate. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: You should also read  [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: If you want to provide both question and answer, that’s fine. However, make sure the question is a question (both title *and* body) and the answer contains the *complete* answer.

Comment: @David: sorry but I not found how I will create article with solution (not question).

Comment: @MichalZobec The point is you ask the question as if you don't know the answer. Then you can add an answer below, pretending you're answering someone else's question. We do this to keep the Q&A format, and it also allows other people add a different answer - they might have a better answer!

Comment: @Bob thanks for explanation, it is my first post, I am very sorry for mistake.

Comment: @MichalZobec on my installation it lists my Microsoft Account email address as the registered/licensed to. Can you provide a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve and why?

Answer (score 3):

I have not found a solution for Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, so I am posting my own experience.

1. Open Registry Editor (*Start*->*Run*->type *regedit*-> press Enter).
2. Find the following key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\
   ```
3. Delete key `14.0_Config\`
4. Find the following key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\
   ```
5. Delete key `14.0\`
6. Navigate to the following folder:

   ```
   C:\Users\{YOUR_USER}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\
   ```

   (Replace `{YOUR_USER}` with your own username.)
7. Delete the folder \14.0\
8. Start Visual Studio, and create a new license registration.